# Process to design a Custom Tab bar

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am trying to create a custom tab bar for a universal application wherein i need to set the frame size accordingly. Kindly help me out with this..

Answer (score 2):

if you are making universal app, so u need to make custom tab bar on the window base project, take image view, uibutton (custum button) ,images as per as your look and set all those accordingly. call the controller on the click of the custom button.